# Since dotnet/sdk:8.0, dotnet restore takes too long on gitlab ci with docker

Tags: .net, docker, nuget, gitlab-ci, maui

I have upgraded my docker dotnet image to `dotnet/sdk:8.0` to build MAUI projects on my Gitlab CI with docker runners.

But now the job takes like 40 minutes to restore the projects (before: 45 seconds):

```
$ dotnet restore --no-cache
Restored /builds/**/A.csproj (in 10.11 min).
Restored /builds/**/B.csproj (in 14.13 min).
Restored /builds/**/C.csproj (in 2.03 min).
Restored /builds/**/D.csproj (in 36.08 min).
```

The ops in charge of the runners tells me that the CPU usage was above 100%.

I have no problem restoring the project on my local machine.

Anyone has already faced this issue after upgrading to .Net 8?

Comment: Same here. Do you have a solution? Will post an update if I found a solution.

Comment: @Bishan yes, follow the link in my answer to get the workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people facing the same issue, this can be fixed by a workaround proposed by NuGet team:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/130624

*Solution:*

**Setting environment variable `DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION` to false fixes the long restore.**

*Explanation:*

In dotnet 8, the NuGet tool tries to verify all package signatures by default (if you are behind a firewall, this can lead to many hidden timeouts)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587